# Iterate JSON data with JavaScript to build alphabetical list

Tags: javascript, json

My JavaScript app receives JSON data from my backend PHP app.  I need to create a page that list all my Tag records sorted into list by alphabet letter that the tag title starts with.

[image]

I have my PHP returning JSON in the format of each letter and under each letter I have my tag records which start with that letter like this:

```
{
   "A":[

   ],
   "B":[

   ],
   "C":[
      {
         "id":"3",
         "title":"CSS",
         "description":""
      },
      {
         "id":"6",
         "title":"CSS3",
         "description":"CSS3 description"
      }
   ],
   "D":[

   ],
   "E":[

   ],
   "F":[

   ],
   "G":[

   ],
   "H":[

   ],
   "I":[

   ],
   "J":[
      {
         "id":"2",
         "title":"JavaScript",
         "description":""
      }
   ],
   "K":[

   ],
   "L":[
      {
         "id":"4",
         "title":"Laravel",
         "description":""
      }
   ],
   "M":[

   ],
   "N":[

   ],
   "O":[

   ],
   "P":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "title":"PHP",
         "description":""
      }
   ],
   "Q":[

   ],
   "R":[

   ],
   "S":[

   ],
   "T":[

   ],
   "U":[

   ],
   "V":[

   ],
   "W":[

   ],
   "X":[

   ],
   "Y":[

   ],
   "Z":[

   ]
}
```

---

Based on my JSON data above, how can I iterate that and build HTML with a Letter heading for each letter and an `<ul>` list under each letter listing the tags under that letter?

Comment: However you like, really - where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: *how can I iterate that* By using JavaScript's iteration features, google for that.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I need with the code below, any improvements always welcome thanks.

[image]

---

```js
var letters = {
  "A": [

  ],
  "B": [

  ],
  "C": [{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "CSS",
    "description": ""
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "title": "CSS3",
    "description": "CSS3 description"
  }],
  "D": [

  ],
  "E": [

  ],
  "F": [

  ],
  "G": [

  ],
  "H": [

  ],
  "I": [

  ],
  "J": [{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "JavaScript",
    "description": ""
  }],
  "K": [

  ],
  "L": [{
    "id": "4",
    "title": "Laravel",
    "description": ""
  }],
  "M": [

  ],
  "N": [

  ],
  "O": [

  ],
  "P": [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "PHP",
    "description": ""
  }],
  "Q": [

  ],
  "R": [

  ],
  "S": [

  ],
  "T": [

  ],
  "U": [

  ],
  "V": [

  ],
  "W": [

  ],
  "X": [

  ],
  "Y": [

  ],
  "Z": [

  ],
  "Other": [{
    "id": "7",
    "title": "1 Non Letter Tag",
    "description": "1 Non Letter Tag"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "title": "_Another non letter tag",
    "description": "_Another non letter tag"
  }]
};

var html = '';
for (var letter in letters) {
  html += '<h2>' + letter + '</h2><ul>';
  for (var bar in letters[letter]) {
    html += '<li><a href="#" class="tag-link" data-id="' + letters[letter][bar]['id'] + '" data-title="' + letters[letter][bar]['title'] + '">' + letters[letter][bar]['title'] + '</a>' +
      '<br><div class="tag-description">' + letters[letter][bar]['description'] + '</div></li>';
  }
  html += '</ul>';
}
$('#tags-by-letter').html(html);
```

```css
#tags-by-letter{
columns: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags-by-letter"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your data has objects inside a object. You have to reiterate inside

```
 $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
      html = "<ul>";
       $.each(obj, function(j, obj1) {
            html += "<li>";
         }
   });
```